# How can I suppress ALL output from gradle?

Tags: gradle, scripting, output, zsh

I'm writing a script for zsh that essentially just needs to know the exit code of the following gradle command: `./gradlew installDebug`. In other words, I don't want *any* output to the console while running this. I've tried the following:

`./gradlew installDebug -q > /dev/null; 2>&1`

This eliminates 99% of the output, but I still get lines like the following:

```
Note: Generating a MembersInjector for com.example.ui.BaseActivity. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
Note: Generating a MembersInjector for com.example.widget.nav.NavigationDrawerActivity. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
Note: Generating a MembersInjector for com.example.fragment.ShiftListFragment. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
```

These warnings are coming from lint, which, in general, I want to keep (for when I build manually, without this script). I simply want to suppress the output in this one specific case.

I feel like I'm simply not redirecting output for a given stream correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are using `zsh` you can use

```
./gradlew installDebug -q &> /dev/null
```

For POSIX compliant shells (including `zsh`) you can use

```
./gradlew installDebug -q > /dev/null 2>&1
```

---

The reason it did not work is the semicolon. A `;` separates two commands but redirections only work per command and not per command-line. So what actually happens is equivalent to the following:

```
./gradlew installDebug -q > /dev/null
2>&1
```

- In the first command the standard output of `./gradlew` is redirected to `/dev/null` but standard error is not changed and thus printed normally.
- The second is actually just a redirection without a command. In this case the behavior depends on the setting of the the parameter `NULLCMD` and the options `SH_NULLCMD` and `CSH_NULLCMD`. By default `zsh` runs `cat` with the given redirection applied.

Comment: @JorgeMachado Can you please explain why this would not work with `println`? Or is this more of an observation that it does not seem to work?

Comment: Because I had the same issue. Running this command as single let's say so it will work. If you use it in the a serie of commands it will break and in my case I was build a version.txt with version=<version>. What I end up having was version=<the println message>. The way to do it properly is not to println on your gradle file. use logger.info("some message instead of println")